# How to disable EMACS - Prelude colors? (terminal)

Tags: terminal, emacs, ubuntu-12.04, colors, themes

I've used [PRELUDE](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) to work better in terminal, but I'd love to work with my default Terminal theme(colors).

Zenburn-theme comes default with Prelude but It just work great the first time i run `emacs` with prelude recently installed. The next times, prelude makes a dark background in the currently working line. It is not cool.

I've used `M-x disable-themes` but I don't get my terminal colors either. Now the working line has a fluorecent green background. Not confortable at all.

How can I run prelude and keep my system terminal colors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also you need to add the `export TERM=xterm-256color` to the .bashrc file to avoid the horrible colors. That way everything work.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the prelude README, try to include in your personal.el customization file

```
(disable-theme 'zenburn)
```

This should provide you a theme-free emacs.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to comment code enabling the theme at *~/.emacs.d/core/prelude-ui.el*. This if better especially for GUI version, as otherwise the theme flashes on startup as it loads and then gets disabled.