# Emacs Prelude: Changing the background Color

Tags: emacs

I installed the Emacs Prelude as suggested in https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude . I find the background-color grey of the Zenburn theme to be disturbing. I wish to change the background-color to black. I tried (set-background-color "black") ,but it is not working. The background-color still remains grey. Can someone help on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also dissable the zenburn theme:

M-x disable-theme

More info here:
[How to disable EMACS - Prelude colors? (terminal)](https://superuser.com/questions/597170/how-to-disable-emacs-prelude-colors-terminal)

And here:
https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude#ugly-colors-in-the-terminal-emacs-version